# Error in javascript code for facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I wrote some code to like all posts on Facebook.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_15ko _5a-2 touchable');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    inputs[i].click();
    };
```

The code is working well but the class  `'_15ko _5a-2 touchable'` is the same class for (unlike) 
So, When I scroll the page , More posts appear and trying to put the code again , The code working well with new posts but it remove likes from old posts.
Is there any solution?

Comment: may i ask what the use case for this is? autoliking is not allowed, so i can´t think of any reason why you would want to do that.

Comment: Hello , this code isn't for autoliking

Comment: I learn Javascript and I'm designing a tool for facebook like (unfollow all , like all posts , remove all requests , etc ) just for learn and Apply what I have learned

Comment: you need to use the graph api for that. what you are doing right now is not allowed.

Comment: what about this ?? 
document.getElementById("div on facebook").innerHTML="<button onClick="......">
div on facebook = any div in facebook

Comment: I tried it and succes

Comment: you need to start reading over there, using the graph api with an app is the only allowed way to interact with facebook like that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to check the innerHTML of the target, if the value is "Like" the click event is activated, if the value is "Dislike" the script ignore, example:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_15ko _5a-2 touchable');
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
    if (inputs[i].innerHTML == "Like") {
    inputs[i].click();
    }
    };
```

This will work if the button is something like:

```
<a class="_15ko _5a-2 touchable">Like</a>
```

To ignore the _2q8z class you can use the length of the className property, example:

```
//_15ko _5a-2 touchable = 21 (length)
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('_15ko _5a-2 touchable');
for(var i=0; i< inputs.length;i++) {
    if (inputs[i].className.length == 21) {
    inputs[i].click();
    }
    };
```

I will put a working example, hope it helps.

```js
function Test() {
var elems2 = 0;
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test1");
for (var x = 0; x < elems.length; x ++) {
elems2 ++;
}
alert(elems2 + " elements");
}

function Filter() {
var elems2 = 0;
elems = document.getElementsByClassName("test1");
for (var x = 0; x < elems.length; x ++) {
if (elems[x].className.length == 5) {
elems2 ++;
}  
}
alert(elems2 + " elements");
}
```

```css
.test1 {
display: block;
padding: 10px;
background: #f1f1f1;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">Element</div>
<div class="test1">Element</div>
<div class="test1">Element</div>
<div class="test1 _2qz8">Element to ignore</div>
<div class="test1 _2qz8">Element to ignore</div>
<input type="button" value="Count All Elements" onClick="Test();">
<input type="button" value="Count only with class test1" onClick="Filter();">
```

Comment: Thanks , Your method is very useful .
But there are problem in facebook.
when I innerHTML , The posts without likes have class : ("_15ko _5a-2 touchable") and the posts with likes have class ("_15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8")
but when I innerHTML like this : 
document.getElementsByClassName("_15ko _5a-2 touchable")
All classes appear even ("_15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8")
But if InnerHTML for ("_15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8")
only classes which have ("_15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8") appear

Comment: Have you tried getElementsByTagName? These classes seem to be very random, maybe if you get the elements by tag name you can be more exactly that you are referring to the like / dislike link itself.

Comment: The tag name of (like button) is <a>
and the name of button is ("Like") even the post have like before , only it's color change 
getElementsByTagName with <a> output very much of results because there are too much have <a>

Comment: [a#u_1q_g._15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8z, a#u_1q_i._15ko._5a-2.touchable, a#u_1q_10._15ko._5a-2.touchable, a#u_1q_w._15ko._5a-2.touchable._2q8z]

Comment: this result above come by (document.getElementsByClassName("_15ko _5a-2 touchable")

Comment: Oh, well, I understand, you may try to check if the className has the _2q8 thing and ignore (I will edit my code) to show how you can do it.

Comment: Added a way to ignore the _2q8 classes and only click in the classes without this.

Comment: Thanks very much <3

Comment: it works well :)
var inpu = document.getElementsByClassName("_15ko _5a-2 touchable")
for(var i=0; i<inpu.length;i++) {
 if(inpu[i].className.length == 21) {
  inpu[i].click()
 };
};